# Angular 5 Symbolic Link Node Modules Bootstrap Issue

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, symlink, node-modules

It is hard to show an example but basically I have an Angular 5 program that uses bootstrap:
`"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", ...]`

What I have been doing lately is creating symbolic links for my "node_modules" folder. Because every Angular app builds its own 200mb "node_modules" folder, and I don't like wasting so much useless space on my laptop.

In all cases the symbolic link "node_modules" folder works perfectly, Angular doesn't have any problem with this. For some reason though, it doesn't activate bootstrap.

My bootstrap works perfectly when I use the "normal" approach, but when I use the symbolic link approach for my "node_modules" folder then bootstrap doesn't load in...or something.

Any idea to a solution for this?